# Is there a way to force read a USB flash drive on OSX 10.6.8 that shows up in the system profiler but not on the desktop?

Tags: snow-leopard, usb, mount

USB High-Speed Bus:

Host Controller Location: Built-in USB
  Host Controller Driver:   AppleUSBEHCI
  PCI Device ID:    0x3b3c 
  PCI Revision ID:  0x0006 
  PCI Vendor ID:    0x8086 
  Bus Number:   0xfa

Hub:

Product ID:   0x2514
  Vendor ID:    0x0424  (SMSC)
  Version:   0.03
  Speed:    Up to 480 Mb/sec
  Location ID:  0xfa100000 / 2
  Current Available (mA):   500
  Current Required (mA):    2

USB Flash Drive:

Product ID:   0xc75c
  Vendor ID:    0x05dc  (Lexar Media, Inc.)
  Version:   1.02
  Serial Number:    20130610231308265957
  Speed:    Up to 480 Mb/sec
  Manufacturer: Lexar
  Location ID:  0xfa130000 / 7
  Current Available (mA):   500
  Current Required (mA):    200

Comment: Open `Disk Utility` and see what partitions are on the drive. If readable by OS X you should be able to mount them.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do it with terminal, in case it's just not mounted automatically

1. Open terminal
2. type `diskutil list` and hit enter
3. Check which disk you want to browse, I'll use `disk3` in this example, and get the `IDENTIFIER` from the line that shows the device name. So in my example the line wold be `2:  Apple_HFS DiskName  999.9 GB   disk3s2`
4. Type `diskutil info /dev/disk3s2` and get the mount point. Mout it with `diskutil mount  /dev/disk3s2`
5. Now it should show up in finder.